# Should this "wasn't" be a "weren't"? Why?

Tags: sentence

> If it wasn't raining I would have gone to work.

I was told this sentence isn't correct, because it should have "weren't" instead of "wasn't":

> If it weren't raining I would have gone to work.

Is this actually true, and if so, why?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for a better understanding of how this site operates. Your question e.g. could be improved if you indicate what specifically you believe is or is not correct, and what research you have attempted thus far and why it is inconclusive. Adherence to standard capitalization and spelling is also a plus. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexhange.com/) may also be of interest, though note that they have similar rules.

Comment: why "weren't"? thank you anyway

Comment: It's weren't because you're using the subjunctive mood. This Grammar Girl post might help you understand it better: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/subjunctive-verbs

Comment: If you question concerns "wasn't" vs. "weren't", you should **say that in your question**. Otherwise, some may think your question is about "i" vs "I", others might wonder if you think the writer shouldn't use a contraction, others might start wondering about "gone to work" vs. "went to work", others might start thinking about whether or not there should be a mid-sentence comma... In other words, be specific and clear about what you are asking about.

Comment: I appreciate all your help guys, thank you. Ye, I realized that. next time I'll be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

No. It should be "If it **weren't** raining, I would have gone to work.

Comment: Please check that an identical (or very similar) question hasn't already been asked and answered before replying to what is a fairly standard query.